# Extract columns with values matching a specific pattern

Tags: linux, r, sed, awk

I have a multi-column GTF file, where each row has different number of columns:

```
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    12659   12721   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.3.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS1";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    13221   16604   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "2"; oId "CUFF.3.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS1";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    29554   30039   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000002"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000002"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "MIR1302-11"; oId "ENST00000473358"; nearest_ref "ENST00000473358"; class_code "="; tss_id "TSS2";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    30564   30667   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000002"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000002"; exon_number "2"; gene_name "MIR1302-11"; oId "ENST00000473358"; nearest_ref "ENST00000473358"; class_code "="; tss_id "TSS2";
chr1    Cufflinks   exon    69091   70008   .   +   .   gene_id "XLOC_000003"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000005"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "OR4F5"; oId "ENST00000335137"; nearest_ref "ENST00000335137"; class_code "="; tss_id "TSS4"; p_id "P1";
```

I only want columns matching the pattern 'gene_id "...";' 'transcript_id "...";' 'class_code "..";'

I tried removing the unwanted columns using:

```
sed -e 's/nearest_ref\s\"[A-Z]\{4\}[0-9]\{11\}\"\;//' -e 's/oId\s\"[A-Z|\.|0-9]*\"\;//' -e 's/gene_name\s\"[A-Z|0-9|\.|\-]*\"\;//' -e 's/contained_in\s\"[A-Z|\_|0-9]*\"\;//' -e 's/p_id*\s\".*\"\;//' merged.gtf > temp.gtf
```

But looks like there are many other unwanted columns in the file that I cannot see (the file is huge). How do I extract the desired columns and save it into another file?

Comment: Are the fields always `gene_id "...";`, `transcript_id "...";` and `class_code "...";`?

Comment: Is there a reason this is tagged [tag:r]?

Comment: the fields are gene_id followed by a space followed by double quotes followed by any number of alpha numeric characters followed by another double quotes followed by a semi-colon.

Comment: I thought maybe someone could help me do this in R.

Comment: Are you still looking for a way to do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind an extra trailing space, and my assumptions in my comment above are true, then the following should work:

```
awk '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /gene_id|transcript_id|class_code/) {
            printf "%s %s ", $i, $(i + 1)
        }
    }
    print ""
}' merged.gtf > temp.gtf
```